# Run Spring Scheduled jobs configured in different modules

Tags: spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have a Spring Boot application where I am using the Spring scheduling to schedule cron jobs. I have 3 different modules in my application: service-toolA, service-toolB and service-application.

My service-application module has the Spring-Boot config and the Application class as follows:

```
package com.service.tool.main;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.service.tool")
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling 
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
 }
```

Now I have my Scheduled jobs in the other modules service-toolA and service-toolB. I have configured them as follows:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 4000)
public void printName() {
   System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

However when I run the application, the Scheduled jobs doesn't get started. They run when I place these Scheduled methods in the service-application module where my Application class is present.

How do I run it in different modules and the config being in service-application module?

Answer (score 1):

Add the package for the class which has the `printName()` to the list of packages scanned, example:

```
@ComponentScan("com.service.tool","com.service.module1")
```

Comment: Still the same issue. It didn't work. Not sure if I need to register the beans for the Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
```

I solved it by adding this annotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mark your class as `@Service` attribute

```
@Service
public class ScheduledTasks {

   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 4000)
   public void printName() {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
   }

}
```

Then add package name in @ComponentScan

```
@ComponentScan({"service-toolA", "service-toolB"})
...
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**
If anyone looking for an fix to this issue.

Add your sub modules  as a dependency in the module where you have Application or @SpringBootApplication. @SpringBootApplication will take care of Componentscan. But you have to follow the same package path for submodules as well.

In the above case add *service-toolA* and *service-toolB* in pom file of *service-application* as a dependency.